# No sound output available after upgrade to 19.10

Tags: upgrade, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, 19.10

Recently, I've gotten stuck in the famous login loop on Ubuntu 19.04. The only way to get out was to upgrade to 19.10. And ever since, I have no sound. Checked the sound settings and saw that there was nothing there.

I've tried force reload alsa, reinstalling pulseaudio and alsa, alsamixer. Nothing has worked out.

[image: An image showing no output devices in Gnome Control Center.]

How can I get my audio devices working again?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem after upgrading to Ubuntu 19.04. It seems that `timitity-daemon` was blocking the audio device on system startup.

So I tried:

```
sudo apt purge timidity-daemon
```

to remove `timidity-daemon` and it worked on my site.

If this doesn't work on your installation, you may reinstall it with:

```
sudo apt-get install timidity
```

Other solutions I found are the same with what you have tried before.

Comment: Can you explain a little more which steps can help OP, and also giving some details about how these steps would work? Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1191768/edit) your answer